# Smooth Conjugate Net vs. Curvature-Line Parametrization

Tags: differential-geometry, curvature

so I was wondering what a smooth conjugate net exactly is, intuitively?
Also, what exactly is a curvature-line parametrization?
What would it mean that a smooth conjugate net is orthogonal? Why is it then a curvature-line parametrization?

Best

Fluffs

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This figure is alone quite informative:

> Kambe, Tsutomu. *Geometrical Theory of Dynamical Systems and Fluid Flows*. No. 23. World Scientific, 2004.
>
> ---
>
> [image: Fig10.1]

---

A second source, with spectacular images:

> Liu, Yang, Weiwei Xu, Jun Wang, Lifeng Zhu, Baining Guo, Falai Chen, and Guoping Wang. "General planar quadrilateral mesh design using conjugate direction field." In *ACM Transactions on Graphics (TOG)*, vol. 30, no. 6, p. 140. ACM, 2011. ([PDF download](http://research.microsoft.com/en-us/um/people/yangliu/publication/cdf.pdf).)
>
> ---
>
> [image: Fig.1]

---

Comment: So a coordinate net is the same as a conjugate net? The curvature-line was defined, s.t. its tangents are in the direction of the principal lines, so are the principal lines tangents to the curvature lines? I´m really confused about this.

Comment: @Fluffy12: The term "coordinate net" is generic, whereas "conjugate net" is a coordinate net with every point crossed by conjugate directions.

Comment: @Fluffy12: And "principle directions" (along principle curvatures) are a special case of conjugate directions.